# Cakephp increasing update a column in the act

Tags: php, cakephp

Good day!

I am running an update on two tables at once , but when I run the query cakephp is increasing the value of a column like a column with auto increment .

I have the following array:

```
$this->request->data = array(
        'Model1' => array(
            'id'=>'9',
            'nome_fantasia' => 'Campos',
            'razao_social' => 'Campos ',
            'email' => 'testes@teste.com.br',
            'responsavel_cpf' => '4456456465',
            'ativo' => '1'
        ),
        'Model2' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '43',
                'relacionamento_id' => '9',
                'endereco' => 'Rua ******',
                'numero' => '123',
                'bairro' => 'bairro',
                'cep' => '033888222'
            )
        )
    );
```

And then the bass I have the update function:

```
$this->Modelo1->id = $this->request->data('Modelo1.id'); 
$this->Modelo1->saveAll( $this->request->data );
```

Ok , it does the Update in Model1 when it runs the update in Modelo2 it saves all the data but in the ' relacionamento_id ' instead of putting '9' as in this-> request- > data it is increasing with some ghost value. .. I realized that every time I run the query it will increase the number , for example

Attempt 1 = relacionamento_id = 50
Attempt 2 = relacionamento_id = 51
Attempt 3 = relacionamento_id = 52
Attempt 4 = relacionamento_id = 53

If I save both models separately it is right, but I would save direct .

Comment: Are you sure this is not set as auto increment field in your db?

Comment: Hi @gmponos, the field is not auto increment